# Activate debug for a library

Tags: c++, debugging, macros

I writing a program in C++ that uses the beaglebone's prussdrv library (http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/PRU_Linux_Application_Loader_API_Guide), importing prussdrv.h in my code so that I can use all the functions defined by it.

However, some of the function calls are returning -1 and I would like to know the exact problem. Seeing the source code (https://github.com/beagleboard/am335x_pru_package/blob/master/pru_sw/app_loader/interface/prussdrv.c) I find that there are many calls that print something to stderr when returning -1:

```
if (fPtr == NULL) {
    DEBUG_PRINTF("File %s open failed\n", filename);
return -1;
} else {
    DEBUG_PRINTF("File %s open passed\n", filename);
}
```

Those DEBUG_PRINTF statements can be replaced by a printf by defining the __DEBUG macro:

```
#ifdef __DEBUG
#define DEBUG_PRINTF(FORMAT, ...) fprintf(stderr, FORMAT, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DEBUG_PRINTF(FORMAT, ...)
#endif
```

However it's not clear how to define it to enable the debugging. I tried compiling my code with -D__DEBUG flag but it didn't work. Is it supposed to? Would it work if I search for the source file in my machine and change it, just leaving the #define ? What is the correct way of enabling debug for imported libraries?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to activate debug printing for the library, you have to compile it with `-D__DEBUG` and then link your code with that debug version of the library.

In other words, you should compile *the library* with this flag, *not your code*. Then you'll have two versions of this library: the production and the debug one. Liking your code with different library versions will result in different behavior.